# Vite Rollup missing exports in Systemjs bundle

Tags: reactjs, bundle, vite, rollup, systemjs

I am using vite in a react TS project. My goal is to build the project into a systemjs bundle.

this is my vite config;

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 8001,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: "src/main.tsx",
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `[name]-chat-fe.js`,
        chunkFileNames: `[name]-chat-fe.js`,
        assetFileNames: `[name]-chat-fe.[ext]`,
        format: "system",
      },
      external: ["@mui/material", "react", "react-dom"],
    },
  },
});
```

The problem is that my exported functions do not end up in `exports` callback function of systemjs in the final bundle.
as an example my bundle looks like this, which is missing  `exports('unmount', unmount);`

```
System.register([], function (exports, module) {
  "use strict";
  return {
    execute: function () {
      function unmount(containerId) {
        // Your code...
      }
    // expect to see  exports('unmount', unmount); here but it is missing
    }
  };
});
```

The simplified version of my main.tsx is:

```
export function unmount(containerId: string) {
  if (rootInstance) {
    rootInstance.unmount();
    rootInstance = null;
  } else {
    console.error(`Application not mounted to "${containerId}"`);
  }
}
```

As a result when importing my systemjs bundle in another app, I can not access the exported functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was setting `preserveEntrySignatures` properly.

```js
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      // Keep exports as defined in source
      preserveEntrySignatures: "allow-extension",
```